# How Does "Use" work in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Hi I have the following Code Snippet;

```
class StringCalci
{
        static def plus(Integer self, Integer Operand)
        {
                return self.toInteger() * Operand.toInteger()
        }
}
use (StringCalci)
{
        println("inside the Use method!")
        println( 12 + 3 )
}
println(12+3)
```

I was been shocked to see the use of `Use` in groovy. The thing is this I can add methods to the Class at run-time(my own methods).when I was looking at the above code, I was Thinking how does Groovy make things possible like this! The use of `println` inside the `Use` is multiplying the two given numbers(because I have Override the `plus` method)  , where as the outside `println` adds it! My question is how does Groovy recognise the `println` executes in `Use` and `println` outside the `Use`. Is `Use` is a keyword/method? I need to understand behind the scenes of this process.. Please let me know :) 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I don't know any Groovy, but from the looks of it, `println` isn't even touched - only `+` is overloaded.

Comment: @Delnam: ya the plus is been overloaded.. But I want to know how does `Use` made this possible!

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of dynamic languages where everything is possible and nothing is certain!

This feature is called [Categories](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Categories). As for the implementation:

- `use` is in fact not a keyword but a method which the Groovy runtime [adds to the `Object` class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html), which makes it available everywhere.
- I think the functionality is implemented mainly in the class [GroovyCategorySupport](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/GroovyCategorySupport.html)
- Judging from the Javadoc, it's based on keeping a map of overriden methods in a `ThreadLocal` which is then consulted for every method call.
- yeah, that's not so great for performance, but so are pretty much all the dynamic "magic" features that Groovy and similar languages offer (and there's lots of them).

Comment: @Micheal : Thanks for your reply :) and ya the answer is in `ThreadLocal`, now will search for this learn more about this :)

Comment: @Micheal : from your answer, the `ThreadLocal` is in java(a feature for static class's, in which each thread have a **number**) in which the groovy takes advantages of it, to implement `Use`, am I right?

Comment: @Aussies: that sounds about right. But note that I'm really only guessing how it might be implemented based on the fact that the javadoc of GroovyCategorySupport mentions a "local thread context".